# clearfix is not working for overflow:auto

Tags: html, css

I am very bad with css, so someone can help me:

I have following html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cluster Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
  <style>
   .square-thumb
    {
        float: left;
        margin:5px !important;
        padding:5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='img-container'>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919812643.jpg'></div>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919814776.jpg'></div>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919816424.jpg'></div>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919817149.jpg'></div>
</div>
<div class='clearfix'></div>
<hr>
<div class='new_div' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid grey;'>
THIS IS MY NEW DIV
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the new_div is not rendered correctly. The background color does not show, the height and width are not there etc.

If I comment the following line in the CSS, it works just fine:

```
float: left;
```

I read somewhere that adding a clearfix div will work but it does not work either. Can anyone help me,I have been stuck for hours now... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that div right after the floated square-thumbs and change from `oveflow:auto` to `clear:both`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cluster Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
  <style>
   .square-thumb
    {
        float: left;
        margin:5px !important;
        padding:5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .clearfix {
      clear:both;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='img-container'>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919812643.jpg'></div>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919814776.jpg'></div>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919816424.jpg'></div>
<div class=' square-thumb'><img src='images1/1919817149.jpg'></div>
<div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='new_div' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid grey;'>
THIS IS MY NEW DIV
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir!! That worked! I will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.